# Shortcut focus mouse in Filter of widget box in Qt Designer?

Tags: qt-designer, pyqt6

I don't know if there is a shortcut that can focus the mouse on the Filter box in the Widget box?
I want to quickly focus mouse to the Filter box to find widgets quickly
The straining to find widgets really tire me out.

I've tried looking in the manual but can't find it mentioned? (link: [https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtdesigner-manual.html])
Can someone help me?

[image: 1]

Comment: Sorry but this is not really a programming question, since it's mostly an UX issue of a specific program, and, as such, off topic: the fact that the program is used for programming aspects is quite irrelevant, as the issue is not directly related to programming issues since it doesn't prevent nor directly affect actual programming.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Basically I also see a question regarding keyboard shortcuts on IDEs(). Using QT Designer is rated as "quick creation of UI" but I find it "slow" as the problem I'm having. Saving time searching can help me spend more time coding

Comment: I really understand your point of view, but I have to disagree: following your query, much broader questions than yours would eventually fit, including "how to automatically run the IDE when my computer starts up", or, why not, even "what's the best body posture for long hours of programming without any need for resting". I agree that there is a thin and blurry line about these topics, but what you're asking doesn't really prevent you from programming nor seriously impede your abilities. I know it can be annoying, but your question doesn't really fit the scope of StackOverflow.

Comment: What does "focus mouse" mean? If you want to start typing in the filter-box, just click on it with the mouse. Or better yet, simply memorise the order of the widgets. I've been using Qt Designer for decades and have never used that filter-box. It's just far too inefficient, since it requires switching back and forth between the keyboard and mouse. Really, I think it's your chosen way of working that's "slow", rather than Qt Designer itself.

Comment: I just started using Qt Designer.
It's true that I want a shortcut to quickly jump to the filter box for typing.
I am imagining that there is a keyboard shortcut (like pressing Alt + Tab will switch the previous application window)